# Change the order of records depending on the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, sql-order-by

Imagine I have a list of todos which are visible by many members of a team. I would like to enable each team member to maintain their own todo list order depending on which todos they think are the most important.

How do I store this ordering at the database level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would store the order as a float (probably called 'position' or something similar) in a join table that connects users and todos. Then when you grab the list, you can specify that order in the relation. One of the major reasons to use `:has_many :through` relationships is when you want to store data about the association itself (rather than about either of the associated models).

Comment: Out of curiousity, why a float?

Comment: @kafuchau A float means you can re-position any element between any two other elements, without renumbering any others. If you're using integers, which is the instinctive choice, then moving item 1 between items 5 and 6 requires renumbering 1 as 6 and 6+ up by one until you hit a space. Using a float means you can simply change 1.0 to 5.5, and if you need another after it, it can be 5.75, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need a separate model which is associated with users and todos. E.g. (assuming that your existing models are called User and Todo:

**app/models/todo_orders.rb**

```
class TodoOrders.rb < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :todo

  validates_uniqueness_of :order_num
end
```

**db/migrate/yyyymmddhhmmss_create_todo_orders.rb**

```
def up
  t.integer :user:id
  t.integer :todo_id
  t.integer :order_num
end
```

You will need some additional logic in your models to pull the right orders and associate them with your todo items. e.g.

**app/models/todo.rb**

```
attr_accessor :cur_order
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
has_many :todo_orders

def get_todos
  todo_orders.includes(:todo).map do |todo_order|
    todo = todo_order.todo
    todo.cur_order = todo_order.order_num
    todo
  end
end
```

Thus calling get_todos on a user object will return a list of Todos with the order the are to be displayed stored in their cur_order attribute

Answer (score 1):

Your database model should look something like this:

[image]

This is a pretty standard many-to-many relationship with the "link" table in the middle, but with one twist: the `ORDER` is part of the alternate key `{USER_ID, ORDER}` (denoted by `U1` in the diagram above) but **not** part of the primary key. This is what makes it **per-user** order.

*(Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Ruby on Rails - this answer is purely from the database modelling perspective.)*